# blocking website pages starting with numbers

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My website has probably been hacked with a conditional redirect. It shows Japanese language in the search result. I have shown a sample link below.

```
https://example.com/11449tkbhb6bvkb1f
```

All the links start with a number as mentioned above.

I have already replaced the code with the backup of the website. However, I want to block all the urls that starts with the number using htaccess. Please suggest.

Comment: _If_ your website "has been hacked", then just trying to block a few requests hardly is an adequate measurement. So you first have to find out if that is the case or not. If it is you need to completely take the site offline until you have really identified the issue and _really_ fixed it. So: what makes you believe that your site "has been hacked"?

Comment: @arkascha Since they have "already replaced the code with the backup", we have to assume the "hack" has been resolved (at least for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably these requests already serve a "404 Not Found" response? (If not then this needs to be resolved. Either these URLs resulted because of a "hack" or because of an error with your app that allowed these URLs to be indexed in the first place.)

However, you can send a "410 Gone" response to help speed up the process of search engines dropping the URLs from the search results.

For example, at the top of the root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Send a 410 for any requests that start with a number
RewriteRule ^\d+ - [G]
```

This will serve a "410 Gone" for any request that "starts with a number".

(You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if this is already present in the file.)